# Designing an XNOR function for real numbers

Tags: calculus, functions

I would like to design a function of $(x,y)$ which gives a large output for large values and $x$ and $y$ and for small values for $x$ and $y$. For values of $x$ and $y$, when one is large and the other one small, it should yield a small output value. What would be a suitable function? This is similar to the concept of Bitwise XNOR but operating on Real Values of $x$ and $y$ instead of bits.

Comment: In what sense do yo use "small", here? Is $0.000000000001$ quite small or is $-10000000000$ quite small?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the  output values are relative, for example, if the output range is between $[0, 1]$ small would refer to values close to $0$ or $0$ itself and high would be $1$. Basically the XNOR operation for real numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll speak to the case where $x,\,y\in[0,\,1]$. This can easily be adapted to other scales for which we have a definition of "small" and "large", by replacing the original $f(x,\,y)$ with a function of the form $g^{-1}(f(g(x),\,g(y)))$.

Usually we define $x\land y$ as $xy$, $x\lor y$ as$$1-(1-x)(1-y)=x+y-xy,$$and $\neg x$ as $1-x$. So xnor is then$$\begin{align}(x\land y)\lor(\neg x\land\neg y)&=(xy)\lor((1-x)(1-y))\\&=xy+(1-x)(1-y)-xy(1-x)(1-y)\\&=1-x-y+xy+x^2y+xy^2-x^2y^2,\end{align}$$which under the convention $z^2=z$ (viz. booleans $0^2=0,\,1^2=1$) becomes$$1-x-y+xy+xy+xy-xy=1-x-y+2xy.$$This looks less surprising if written as $x(1-y)+(1-x)y$ before staring at the [logic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate).

Comment: Very nice!   Perhaps combine with a sigmoid to cover "large" and "small" values.

Comment: @mjw I was going to say that's what my first paragraph alluded to, but it occurs to me you might set up something more general where the output's set of possible values isn't the same as for each input. However, I'd advise against that so we can keep combining logical operators.

Comment: Okay, that's what $g^{-1}(f(g(x),\,g(y)))$ is refering to, but more generally, allowing for other possibilities?  There are a family of functions used in neural networks:  $\texttt{sigmoid}(\cdot ),$ $\tanh(\cdot)$, etc.  But maybe you are alluding to other types of functions as well?

Comment: @mjw Feel free to wrap it in another function, despite my previous advice.

Comment: @J. G., That could be done as the very last step and would not affect combining logical operators.  Your advice is well taken.